# How to use label inside my own function C# (windows forms application)

Tags: c#, winforms

Label and my function [image]

So I've got my Form label and one function I wrote myself.
Now inside that function I call label1.Text and It won't pass the compiler.
Don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anyone suggest me a solution?

Inside my function 
[image]

Comment: Don't link to pictures.  Put code and associated error messages directly in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`label1.Text="blah blah blah"` not `label1.Text("blah blah blah")`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Label1.Text` as a function which is wrong since `Text` is a property. The correct way to do it is `Label1.Text = "some text"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to:

```
Label1.Text = "Your string goes here.";
```

The [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) value of your `label` is a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), not a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

To set the text in a label you  have to do:

```
label1.Text="hello world"
```

you are instead using it as it were a method call

```
label1.Text("hello world") //wrong!!!
```